# What is the best Malayalam Mahabharata story book?

Tags: mahabharata

What is the best  book for reading the story of Mahabharata in Malayalam.

Answer (score 1):

This article found helpful:

https://medium.com/p/7beb9bca8fcc

Vyaasa mahabharatham 6 volumes By : vidwan k prakasam , Publisher:- DC Books ,Kottayam

OR

Sampoorna Mahabharatham (malayalam) By Balakrishna Warrier
Publisher: Samrat Publisher, Thrissur

Answer (score 0):

There is a two-volume set published by Sri Ramakrishna Math, Thrissur, and another 2 volume set from Sivananda Ashram, Palakkad.

I am just pointing you to these as well. I haven't read these. BORI and Bibek Debroy's editions are yet to be translated to the best of my knowledge.